# Forge viewer does not load model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I followed this tutorial and it works locally:
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels

As a test i published it to Azure here:
https://forgetest120200707193619.azurewebsites.net/

Seems to work fine as you login.
But the viewer does not load the model when you click on a version of a file.

When i debug this using just F5, same login appears of course.
And the viewer works.

So the viewer loads the model when debugging but not on the website.
So its hard to debug when it works in debug but not when published :-)

Any ideas what might be causing this ?

Comment: You site works on my Mac with Chrome and Firefox: I can see my models in the Viewer 
Could you please provide more information?
1) what exactly happens when the model does not load: any error messages in the UI or in the Developer Console of the browser?
2) which browsers did you test this in?